# "Object Invalid or no Longer Set" when using Variable to Reference Collection

Tags: vba, ms-access

In the process of answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56612617/7531598), I wrote a simple function to test whether an MS Access table contained all fields in a supplied array:

```vb
Function ValidateFields(strTbl As String, arrReq As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim fld
    Dim fldTmp As Field
    On Error GoTo err
    For Each fld In arrReq
        Set fldTmp = CurrentDb.TableDefs(strTbl).Fields(fld)
    Next fld
    ValidateFields = True
err:
    Exit Function
End Function
```

```vb
?ValidateFields("TempTable", Array("Field1", "Field2", "Field3"))
False
```

This performs as expected, however, to improve the efficiency I tried assigning the Fields Collection to a variable outside of the `For Each` loop:

```
Function ValidateFields(strTbl As String, arrReq As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim fld
    Dim fldTmp As Field
    Dim colFld As Fields
    Set colFld = CurrentDb.TableDefs(strTbl).Fields
    On Error GoTo err
    For Each fld In arrReq
        Set fldTmp = colFld(fld)
    Next fld
    ValidateFields = True
err:
    Exit Function
End Function
```

And now, if I comment out the `On Error` statement, I receive the following error with the line `Set fldTmp = colFld(fld)` highlighted as the cause:

> Run-time error '3420':
>   Object invalid or no longer set.

Why would the variable `colFld` lose its value within the `For Each` loop?

Comment: Note that the *-vba tags are [gone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393153/status-of-removing-the-excel-vba-and-similar-vba-tags). I'm not a huge fan of how this went down, but it's done and not worth fighting against.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is:

`CurrentDb` creates a `DAO.Database` object of the currently open database. Your `TableDef` is a member of that.

But since you're not storing that object, it gets closed and deallocated right after you copied the tabledef to an object, and with it the members will be deallocated too.

Store the database object, and the members will also persist:

```
Function ValidateFields(strTbl As String, arrReq As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim fld
    Dim fldTmp As Field
    Dim colFld As Fields
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set colFld = db.TableDefs(strTbl).Fields
    On Error GoTo err
    For Each fld In arrReq
        Set fldTmp = colFld(fld)
    Next fld
    ValidateFields = True
err:
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: Maybe add the strange fact that DAO.Recordsets have a` .Parent` property, that prevents the copy of the Database (usuallay equal to DbEnginge(0)(0)`) being destroyed as the is still a reference left in Recordset.Parent`,that point to that copy.

Comment: And the warning not to use in loops (e.g`For n = 1 to 10000 CurrentDb.Execute SQL Next n`) should be mandatory.

Comment: And the scope of an objects instance is important for that too.